# How to switch the imaginary and reall parts for thrust complex vector

Tags: c++, cuda, thrust

I want to construct a structure which returns a thrust complex number that switch the imaginary and real parts. But my code can't work. The error is " no suitable conversion function from "thrust::complex" to "double" exists " Here is my code.

```
struct im_harmonic
{
  im_harmonic(){}
  __device__ double operator()(thrust::complex<double>x){
   thrust::complex<double> z;
   z.real(x.imag());
   z.imag(-x.real());
   return z;
  }
}
```

Comment: Return value of operator is `double`, is it?

Answer (score 2):

Your operator declares to return `double`, but in the body you return a value of type `thrust::complex`. That's why the error "no suitable conversion from complex to double". To overcome this, you'd probably have to declare your operator to return a complex value:

```
thrust::complex<double> operator()(thrust::complex<double>x) { ..
```